# Connection problem in smack api

Tags: java, android, connection, smack

I am using smack api for file transfer,
there am using connetion

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
            "198.162.1.24",5222);
```

but i know that port `7777` for filetransfer ,when I try to connect with that, my android app becomes force closed because of not connecting to the server.

how do  I transfer the file ..

thanks in advance.

Comment: to implement this you need to have a server

Comment: @Rosalie No, with [SMACK 3.2 comes a local Socks5 proxy](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/changelog.html)

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you are not using the native smack jar you need the ported or the patched one (asmack) to because native smack wont work n android

then try these configurations

```
   SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(15000);
   ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host, port);
   connectionConfig.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
   connectionConfig.setSendPresence(true);
   connectionConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
   connectionConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
   connection = new XMPPConnection(connectionConfig);
```